How to pull a range of values and add it to a date depending on it meeting a certain condition
Am trying to automatically sum up Dates based on a certain size of a feature and it's estimate and I am wondering if we can do this without if statements?
So If I enter a new feature of a certain size among Low, Medium, High etc and enter one of these as an upcoming feature and give a start date, I want the rest of the dates to be populated automatically.
List of values:
      Low Medium High (Feature Sizes)

A.        5.      10.        20
B         12       12       12
C         0        5          15
Desired table: ( I just give details in column A, B, C and it fetches values in columns D & E based on the value in Column C)



Feature Name
Feature Start
Feature Size
A
B




X
11/01/2024
High
=(11/01/2024) + 5 = 11/06/2024
= 11/06/2024+12 = 11/18/2024


Y
12/01/2024
Low
12/06/2024
=12/18/2024



I know I can do it with multiple ifs but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing what I am currently doing.

For A, High, I think it should be (11/01/2024) + 20 ??

Perhaps you could use CHOOSE and SWITCH functions? your requirement is not very clear; where is that 'list of values'; is it ok to build it into the formula; or is it a range.

If data in you desired table is always in the order of A, B,C and Low, Medium, High, you won't even need If or Lookups, just =StartDate + Range will work.

Sorry I should have mentioned that I am working on google spreadsheet which doesn't have a RANGE function.

Better to use ranges, but logic is like:
=B6+INDEX({5,10,20;12,12,12;0,5,15},{1,2,3},XMATCH(C6,{"Low","Medium","High"}))
